# Obtaining specific SocketChannel for OP_WRITE modification and write operation

Tags: java, nio, java-io

I am implementing a simple chat server using Java NIO for performance reasons and I have read from several sources where they advised against registering a `SocketChannel` with a `Selector` to listen to both read and write events at the same time, but only register for write event when there is data available to be written.

Now what I don't know is how to obtain a specific `SocketChannel` object for `OP_WRITE` modification and write operation.

Here is the scenario, 20 chat clients establishes a connection with the chat server at a given time. ChatClient 1 sends a message that is meant to be delivered to ChatClient 15. After reading the data from ChatClient 1's `SocketChannel`, how do I obtain ChatClient 15's `SocketChannel` specifically which I intend to modify to `OP_WRITE` and then write the data meant for it.

I don't know if this approach will work, but I was thinking of adding the `SocketChannel` object returned when `ServerSocketChannel.accept()` method is called to a list with an index that can be used to look it up later. So when there is data available to be written to Client 15, I look up the `SocketChannel` object from the list and then perform the `OP_WRITE` modification and then write the data. Will this work?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a data structure problem. You know which client you want to write to, so you just need a data structure you can get his SocketChannel from. You can key it any way you like: a sequential index, a client identifying string, his IP address; whatever works for your application.

Comment: you have solved half my problem by these words, "data structure problem". Now the other half is that, if I understand you clearly, you are suggesting I can maintain a list of the `SocketChannel` objects and then look them up when there is data available to be written to them? If that is the case, can `Hashtable` work for these purpose as I can use an identifying string to add objects to it? Also, will `Hashtable` perform well with over 1000 objects? Finally, as a side question, is Java NIO performance in 'non-blocking' mode significantly better than Java IO?

Comment: It's still just a data structure problem. Yes you can use a `Hashtable` or `HashMap`. Both will work well with millions of objects. The only compelling reason to use NIO is scalability, not performance. The performance of reading and writing over the network is ultimately limited by the network, not by the code at either end, unless it's incredibly poorly written.